# Oracle - removing starting zero's from string value

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am using a query

```
SELECT CAST(000027 AS VARCHAR2(15)) FROM dual;
```

but this removes the starting 0000 zero's and return me 27 only.

How can I make it return 000027?

Answer (score 1):

The value `000027` and `27`, both as numbers, are identical to Oracle, and it won't "see" the leading zeroes.  The closest thing to what you want here might be to left pad the number/string with zeroes, to a fixed length.  Assuming you want a numerical string of length 6, you could try:

```
SELECT LPAD(CAST(000027 AS VARCHAR2(15)), 6, '0')
FROM dual;
```

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

Use a string literal instead of a numeric literal:

```
SELECT CAST('000027' AS VARCHAR2(15)) FROM dual
```

though the cast may be redundant anyway depending on what you are trying to do.

If you are stuck starting from a number then it's probably losing the leading zeros earlier than you think, as numbers don't actually have those.

If you know how many digits there should be then you can pad, or use `to_char()` instead of `cast()`:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(000027, 'FM000000') FROM dual
```

If you need to you can still cast that to `varchar2(15)`, but not sure why what would be needed unless you're using this as part of a CTAS statement.